# Change value in 2nd row if PDFPTable of iTextSharp in C#

Tags: c#, itext

I have generated PDF file using "iTextSharp" API properly.

Now i want to add total quantity in second row, how i can change value in second row after writing last row of table.

Any ideas.

I have created one table with suppose 3 columns.
Then added 3 rows in table.
After third i want to change value in first row, is it possible ?
How can i do this in C# ?

Thanks.

Comment: If the PDF with the original table has already been serialized (written to byte[] or file), there is no information anymore in it that there is a table, there merely are some glyphs and lines arranged on the backdrop.

Comment: You could add a `PdfTemplate` in a cell event, and add content to that `PdfTemplate` later in the process.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for suggestion, I will search for "PdfTemplate" and try to use it. Does you have any code snippet so that it will help me for how ti use it.